# Pandas pd.cut labels with dollar sign

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas' `pd.cut` method ([link to documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html)) has a `labels` parameter that directs how each cut bin will be labeled (the documentation uses the examples 'low', 'medium', 'high' for each bin.

I am trying to use the dollar signs ($) for labeling but `pd.cut` (although, correctly categorizes the bins) is not showing the dollar sign in the dataframe.

For this dataframe:

```
    Salary
0   50000
1   50000
2   50000
```

I apply the following:

```
bins = [0, 35000, 50000, 75000, 100000]
group_names = ['<=$35K', '$35K-$50K', '$50K-$75K', '$75K-$100K']

DF.loc[:,'category'] = pd.cut(DF.Salary, bins, labels=group_names)
```

But this results in the following :

[image]

And what I want is this:

```
    Salary   Category
0   50000    $35K-$50K
1   50000    $35K-$50K
2   50000    $35K-$50K
```

Can you help me out?

Comment: Try escaping the dollar signs. I.e., `group_names = ['<=\$35K', '\$35K-\$50K', '\$50K-\$75K', '\$75K-\$100K']`

Comment: Yup, that did it.  Thank you.  Post as an answer, and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dollar signs are special characters and used in regexes, so you have to escape them if you want them to appear in your data.

Changing the strings to the following informs python that the dollar signs are part of the strings.

```
group_names = ['<=\$35K', '\$35K-\$50K', '\$50K-\$75K', '\$75K-\$100K']
```